# full div area onclick

Tags: javascript, html

### This problem was not solved.. it was just evaded.. so dont use this as reference

what i have is

```
<div>
    <img onclick='this.style.display="none";this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style.display="block";this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style.width=this.offsetWidth+"px";this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style.height=this.height+"px";' src='http://static.***.pl/cache/***.pl/math/cafc682a15c9c6f1b7bb41eb004d6c45935cbf06434221f7201665f85242cb94.png'/>
    <div onclick='this.style.display="none";this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].style.display="inline";' style='display:none'>
        <pre style='width:100%;height:100%;'>
            \lim_{t\to\infty}\int\limits_1^{t} \frac{1}{x^2}\,dx=\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)\bigg|_1^t=\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{t}-\left(-\frac{1}{1}\right)\right)=\kappa=1880154404
        </pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

yes i know its ugly but well..

my problem is when i click the image it does what i want but if i then click the div it only works if i click on the text and i want it to work for the full div !

i dont want to use document.getElementById etc...

there will be multiple instances of this code and it will be in unknown places.

i really dont want to write up bloated code to do this (this includes jQuery,flash,.NET, Zend Engine etc etc...)

my question is simple :

**why the hell does it work only if i click on text and how to fire onclick for the whole div**

Comment: Would a jQuery based answer be useful?

Comment: nope. i dont like the idea of including 1000s of lines of code to do something that will take 4 lines in pure js...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your original Javascript action, you were setting the width and height of your div to zero, which means that there is no area to click on.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/ndKqM/

which should demonstrate the fix.  I added some background color and padding to show the dimensions of the various boxes.

I removed the parts of the JS that calculated width and height and that fixed the issue.

If you click on the lime green area that holds your text, the action works.

Unless there is some other reason, you don't need to adjust width or height.

Comment: You would need to check `this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style.width=this.offsetWidth` to see what it returns...

Comment: it set the width/height earlier. im confused to see that removing the width setting code and setting bg colors changes the behavior. i didnt set the size to zero - add an alert to see that .... and width:500px; is bad because i dont know the size of the image

Comment: The issue was not JavaScript, but more of a CSS problem.

Comment: The colors are not relevant, just for demo.

Comment: i dont have time to dive in this wierd issue now so i will accept your answer because you provided working code. this would not fix my problem though just change the way i do things.... and im going to just alert the code to the user cause im sick of this :D

Comment: i know the color is not relevant.... ech.. people if this problem was easy i would fix it in 2 seconds. none of you see what the problem was and try to find additional which dont exist . but fair enough - topic closed :D

Comment: If I understand you, you want to get the dimensions of the original image and then do what?

Comment: i dont want to do nothing of this sort. that was allready done.. the problem was that after setting the size (and YES I did set it (i alerted the value to double check)) from js, the div reacted only when you clicked on the text while i wanted it to react to a click anywhere in its new body.. irrelevant, i dont need an answer anymore

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what behavior you really want.

You are setting the image to display:none, and then you set the style.height and style.width of the sibling div to image.height and image.width.  So - those will both be zero (as display:none is set for the image).

Do yourself a favor and set background colors or borders for your divs so you can see what's going on as you code.

Comment: i know whats going on. you dont :) look thru the code again it makes sense.. and the size sets okay. i bolded out what i want. i want the whole div area to react to clicks not just the area where the text is

Comment: The reason that your div is not responding to clicks is because you set its height and width to 0 (try setting height and width to that of the image BEFORE you hide the image).  So only stuff within that div (the PRE) is visible, and responds to clicks.

Comment: okay. if you say so. i wont argue. but i know that its height/width CANT be 0 or i need new glasses/monitor/brain

Comment: new browser maybe?  I tried it in firefox and hiding the img did cause its height and offsetWidth to return zero.  Setting the div dimensions to those values before hiding the img worked however (but since the image I tested with was very small so was the div!)  I'm sure you are using images within which the latex stuff fits better.

Answer (score -1):

Use an A tag with your onclick event and a null URL `href="javascript://"` instead of a DIV

Comment: and write the code to find the correct tag in the document ... yea... i really want to use div and i cant see how this would help ?